# How to access a boolean variable that is inside the Component?

Tags: flutterflow

I have a component that has a boolean variable (pressed) that indicates whether it is pressed or not. This component is repeated as shown in the image about 15 times and I need at a given moment to change the state variable of all of them (refresh)

And I've been trying for a long time and I can't find a way to do it.

What is the solution ?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

bool globalPressed = false;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('State Management'),
        ),
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 15,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return YourComponent();
      },
    );
  }
}

class YourComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('Component'),
      onTap: () {
        globalPressed = !globalPressed;
        (context as Element).markNeedsBuild();
      },
      trailing: globalPressed ? Icon(Icons.check) : null,
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, I have defined a globalPressed boolean variable to represent state of components. Each instance of YourComponent reads from this global variable to determine whether it should display checkmark icon. When component is tapped, it toggles value of globalPressed and triggers rebuild of all instances of YourComponent by calling markNeedsBuild() on context's root widget. This forces all widgets to rebuild and reflect updated state.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not working in Flutter but in FlutterFlow. Anyway, I later have the possibility to get a little hands on the code. But it happens that the components are not inside a ListView but rather a row. I did it this way because with the listView I had problems adjusting the size properly